# What happens if I returns false for a method in Android?

Tags: java, android

Even we return false, the method executed then what is the use of returning false for a boolean method in android?

Can anybody explain to me?

Below is the sample code

```
public boolean addOne(UserModel userModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(USERNAME, userModel.getUserName());
        cv.put(PASSWORD, userModel.getPassword());
        cv.put(SUBSCRIPTION, userModel.isSubscribed());

        long insert = database.insert(USERS_DATA_TABLE, null, cv);
        if (insert == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uhm... my Android knowledge may be a bit rusty, but isn't `onClick` a method that returns nothing (`void`)? Can you please share this code that returns a boolean?

Comment: This is probably a reference to onTouch() from the OnTouchListener interface, it returns a boolean. Some other methods from View interfaces also return booleans. I guess that's what RealTechHacks is talking about.

Answer (score 3):

`onClick` method doesn't return anything, as in [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View))

maybe you are mixing with `onLongClick`, as in [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener#onLongClick(android.view.View)):

> Returns boolean   true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

when you are creating new question you should almost always post relevant code

edit due to pasted code into question, not relevant to clicking `View`s at all...:

[`database.insert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) will return `-1` when it won't insert anything in fact due to some error

> Returns long  the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

so `addOne` method returns then `false` for knowing that insertion wasn't successful

Comment: He's probably talking about onTouch() from the OnTouchListener interface, it returns a boolean. Some other methods from View interfaces also return booleans. I guess that's what RealTechHacks is talking about.

Comment: i think there are quite a few methods where this is applicable, in general if something returns true or false, it's to indicate whether you've handled the operation or not, right